# C++ deleting line of text in a file

Tags: c++, file

I have a problem with my c++ program... My whole program is a database for student names, grades and ages and I have a problem with function when user wants to delete data for 1 student. Here is the code:

```
void deletestudentdata()
{
    string name, grade, tname;
    int age, x=0; // x - "counter" to check if user entered wrong name

    system("cls");
    cout << "Enter name of the student you want to erase from database" << endl;
    cin >> tname;

    ifstream students("students.txt");
    ofstream temp("temp.txt"); // temp file for input of every student except the one user wants to delete

    while(students >> name >> grade >> age)
    {
        if(tname!=name){ // if there are students with different name, input their data into temp file
            temp << name << ' ' << grade << ' ' << age << endl;
        }
        if(tname==name){ // if user entered correct name, x=1 for later output message that the user data has been deleted
            x=1;
        }
    }
    students.clear(); // clear eof and fail bits
    students.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    students.close();
    temp.close();
    remove("students.txt"); 
    rename("temp.txt","students.txt");
    if(x==0){ // x was set to 0 at start, so if it didn't change, it means user entered the wrong name
        cout << "There is no student with name you entered." << endl;
    }
    else{ // x is not 0, it means user entered the correct name, print message that students data has been deleted
        cout << "Student data has been deleted." << endl;
    }
}
```

It works, but the problem is that I enter student data and when I want to delete it via this function it doesn't delete it, I first have to close the program and then reopen the program and then call that function so it deletes students data.

How can I change it so I can delete students data right after inputing, without having to close the program first?

Comment: Can you be more precise with the way you execute it, for example: `"I enter student data"`, how?

Comment: I ran it in VS2012. Did't see any issue.

Comment: Presumably you store the list of student names somewhere else during the run of your program, not just in the file, and you need to remove the student from there too. (Or clear the list and fill it back in as you copy the names over.)

Comment: Can you show us the code for verifying that a student was infact deleted?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work when the student name is not found it just say student name deleted instead of saying it wasn't found

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;




void displaystudentdata()
{
   string name, grade, tname;
    int age, x=0; // x - "counter" to check if user entered wrong name

    system("cls");

    ifstream students("students.txt");


    cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
    while(students >> name >> grade >> age)
    {

        cout<<"Name= "<<name <<", Grade= "<< grade <<" , Age= " <<age<<"\n";
    }
    students.clear(); // clear eof and fail bits
    students.seekg(0, ios::beg);
     students.close();
}

void deletestudentdata()
{
    string name, grade, tname;
    int age, x=0; // x - "counter" to check if user entered wrong name



    ifstream students("students.txt");
    ofstream temp("temp.txt"); // temp file for input of every student except the one user wants to delete


    cout<<"-------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";

    cout << "Enter name of the student you want to erase from database >" << endl;
    cin >> tname;

    //ifstream students("students.txt");
    //ofstream temp("temp.txt"); // temp file for input of every student except the one user wants to delete

    while(students >> name >> grade >> age)
    {
        if(tname!=name){ // if there are students with different name, input their data into temp file
            temp << name << ' ' << grade << ' ' << age << endl;
        }
        if(tname==name){ // if user entered correct name, x=1 for later output message that the user data has been deleted
            x=1;
        }
    }
    students.clear(); // clear eof and fail bits
    students.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    students.close();
    temp.close();
    remove("students.txt"); 
    rename("temp.txt","students.txt");
    if(x==0){ // x was set to 0 at start, so if it didn't change, it means user entered the wrong name
        cout << "There is no student with name you entered." << endl;
    }
    else{ // x is not 0, it means user entered the correct name, print message that students data has been deleted
        cout << "Student data has been deleted." << endl;
    }
}


int main(void)
{



  displaystudentdata();
  deletestudentdata();
  displaystudentdata();
  cout << "Student data has been deleted. \n\n" << endl;
  cout<<" \nPress any key to continue\n";
  cin.ignore();
  cin.get();

   return 0;
}
```